# MySql error 1064 on trigger createion with if statement

Tags: mysql

Below is the code. All I want to do is check if a quote exists and, if not, insert the record into another table.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `CB2`;
CREATE TRIGGER CB2
AFTER UPDATE
ON `quotes` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (SELECT quoteID FROM booking WHERE quoteID <> new.`quoteID`) THEN
INSERT INTO `booking`(`Book_ID`, `Date`, `CustomerID`, `CustodianID`, `cusCntNum`, `Service`, `sAddress`, `Size`, `Comments`, `Frequency`, `Duration`, `Bdrms`, `Bathrm`, `Living Spaces`, `AppointmentStartDate`, `Time`, `ServiceDay`, `AddOns`, `Fee`, `quoteID`, `uBookingID`) VALUES (NULL, CURRENT_DATE, new.CustAccNum, new.CustodianNum, new.Contact_Number, new.ServType,new.Address, new.CommercialSize, new.Comments, new.Frequency, new.Duration, new.Bedrooms, new.Bathrooms, new.lSpaces, new.AppointmentDate, new.AppointmentTime ,DAYOFWEEK(new.AppointmentTime), new.sAddOns, new.Fee, new.quoteID,'');
END IF;
END
```

Comment: Should this be an INSERT trigger?

Answer (score 0):

You need DELIMITER so that mysql can identify whyt belongs to the trigger

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `CB2`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER CB2
AFTER UPDATE
ON `quotes` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (SELECT quoteID FROM booking WHERE quoteID <> new.`quoteID`) THEN
INSERT INTO `booking` 
(`Book_ID`, `Date`, `CustomerID`, `CustodianID`, `cusCntNum`, `Service`, `sAddress`, `Size`, `Comments`, `Frequency`, `Duration`, `Bdrms`, `Bathrm`, `Living Spaces`, `AppointmentStartDate`, `Time`, `ServiceDay`, `AddOns`, `Fee`, `quoteID`, `uBookingID`) VALUES 
(NULL, CURRENT_DATE, new.CustAccNum, new.CustodianNum, new.Contact_Number, new.ServType,new.Address, new.CommercialSize, new.Comments, new.Frequency, new.Duration, new.Bedrooms, new.Bathrooms, new.lSpaces, new.AppointmentDate, new.AppointmentTime ,DAYOFWEEK(new.AppointmentTime), new.sAddOns, new.Fee, new.quoteID,'');
END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You do need to set delimiters but you also need an existence check. Using a simplified version of your model

```
drop table if exists quotes,booking;
create table quotes(quoteid int, val int);
create table booking(quoteid int,val int);

drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter $$

CREATE TRIGGER t
AFTER UPDATE
ON `quotes` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    insert into debug_table(msg) values (new.quoteid);
    IF not exists (SELECT quoteID FROM booking WHERE quoteID = new.`quoteID`) THEN
        INSERT INTO `booking`( `quoteID`,val) VALUES (new.quoteid,new.val);
    END if;
end $$

delimiter ;
truncate debug_table;
insert into quotes(quoteid) values (1),(2);
update quotes set val = 10 where quoteid = 1;
update quotes set val = 20 where quoteid = 1;

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from booking;
+---------+------+
| quoteid | val  |
+---------+------+
|       1 |   10 |
+---------+------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from debug_table;
+----+------+
| id | msg  |
+----+------+
|  1 | 1    |
|  2 | 1    |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

You don't need the debug table but it provides proof that the trigger fired twice as expected.
BTW I'm not convinced that your logic is sound.

Comment: Thank you, What is the best way to go about doing this ?